# restoring DynamoDB table from AWS Backup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-backup

I am using AWS Backup to back up some DynamoDB tables. Using the AWS Backup console to restore the back-ups I am prompted to restore to a new table. This works fine but my tables are deployed using CloudFormation, so I need the restored data in the existing table.

What is the process to get the restored data into the existing table? It looks like there are some third-party tools to copy data between tables but I'm looking for something within AWS itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time, AWS has no direct way to do this (though it looks like you can export to some service, then import from that service into an existing table).

I ended up writing my own code to do this.

Answer (score 5):

I recently had this issue and actually got cloudformation to work quite seamlessly. The process was

1. Delete existing tables directly from dynamodb (do not delete from cloudformation)
2. Restore backup to new table, using the name of the deleted table
3. In cloudformation, detect drift, manually fix any drift errors in dynamodb, and then detect drift again

After this, the CFN template was healthy

Comment: Ah neat - I didn't know what detect drift was until I read this - sounds like a life-saver!

Comment: Same here, did exactly the steps from the answer and it all worked like a charm, thanks @Shane!